For a morphism of varieties how can we write preimage of a irreducible subset as a union of irreducible subsets.
[From: Algebraic Geometry-Andreas Gathmann- 2002-2003 lecture notes]
Lemma 4.1.4.
(i) If $\emptyset \neq X_0 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq X_n=X$ is a longest chain in $X$ then $\operatorname{dim} X_i=i$ for all $i$.
(ii) If $Y \subsetneq X$ is a closed subvariety of the variety $X$ then $\operatorname{dim} Y<\operatorname{dim} X$.
(iii) Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a surjective morphism of projective varieties. Then every longest chain $\emptyset \neq Y_0 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq Y_n$ in $Y$ can be lifted to a chain $\emptyset \neq X_0 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq X_n$ in $X$ (i.e e the $X_i$ are closed and irreducible with $f\left(X_i\right)=Y_i$ for all $i$ ). In particular, $\operatorname{dim} X \geq \operatorname{dim} Y$.
Proof. (i): It is obvious that $\operatorname{dim} X_i \geq i$. If we had $\operatorname{dim} X_i>i$ there would be a longer chain in $X_i$ than $\emptyset \neq X_0 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq X_i$. This chain could then be extended by the $X_j$ for $j>i$ to a chain in $X$ that is longer than the given one.
(ii): We can extend a longest chain $\emptyset \neq Y_0 \subsetneq Y_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq Y_n=Y$ in $Y$ to a chain $\emptyset \neq Y_0 \subsetneq$ $Y_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq Y_n=Y \subsetneq X$ in $X$ which is one element longer.
(iii): We prove the statement by induction on $n=\operatorname{dim} Y$; there is nothing to show if $n=$ 0 . $\color{red}{\textrm{Otherwise let}}$ $Z_1, \ldots, Z_r \subset X$ $\color{red}{\textrm{be the irreducible components of}}$ $f^{-1}\left(Y_{n-1}\right)$, so that $f\left(Z_1\right) \cup$ $\cdots \cup f\left(Z_r\right)=Y_{n-1}$. Note that $Y_{n-1}$ is irreducible and the $f\left(Z_i\right)$ are closed by corollary...........
Question: How do we assume the red sentence? $X$ is irreducible so it doesnot have any other irreducible component?

Not sure what is the question. $f^{-1}(Y_{n-1})$ itself might not be irreducible, but it has finitely many irreducible components. So we denote them by $Z_1,...,Z_r$.

Why it has finitely many irreducible components? Why finite i mean?

Every Noetherian space has finitely many irreducible components.

It is already irreducible(definition of a variety) so it has just 1 irreducible component which is itself and these $Z_i$ are the same and just $X$ the whole space, thats why I dont understand this decomposition?

We are not decomposing $X$, we are decomposing its subspace $f^{-1}(Y_{n-1})$, which has no reason to be irreducible.

Okay, $X$ is variety so noetherian and every subspace of a Noetherian space is Noetherian i.e. it has a finite decomposition of irreducible subsets in it (in this case it is $f^{-1}(Y_i)$). Thanks. The book doesnot underline this noetherian condition. But at the end it is almost trivial. Thank you
